# php ::Array references

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

any idea why

```
foreach ($groups as &$group)
  $group = trim(str_replace(',', '', $group));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($groups);
echo '</pre>';

$groupsq = $groups;
foreach ($groupsq as &$group)
  $group = '\'' . $group . '\'';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($groups);
echo '</pre>';
```

Yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => Fake group
    [1] => another group
    [2] => non-existent
)
Array
(
    [0] => Fake group
    [1] => another group
    [2] => 'non-existent'
)
```

The part i am interested in is,

Why does the second array modification effect the last item on the first array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to clean up the references after each foreach loop using `unset()`, like so:

```
foreach ($groups as &$group)
  $group = trim(str_replace(',', '', $group));

unset($group);

// ...

foreach ($groupsq as &$group)
  $group = '\'' . $group . '\'';

unset($group);
```

Secondly, you're printing `$groups` instead of `$groupsq`:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($groups);
echo '</pre>';
```

The last item of `$groups` is being modified because you didn't clean up the reference after the first foreach loop.

Comment: Cheers, I meant to print $group twice to show the difference.

Why do I need to clean it up, Is the $group variable not scoped to the foreach statement? (although yes you are correct that fixed it)

Comment: @Hailwood: It's not. I don't know the technical bits behind why it's left there after the loop, but it's as such so you need to clean it up.

Comment: PHP has no block scope. Once you create a variable in a function it will continue to exist in that function until you explicitly unset it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an in-depth article explaining the technical details behind this behavior: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html